# How to set the color of the cursor in Geany?

Tags: geany

I'm using Geany on Windows and would like to set the cursor colour to something more conspicuous. 
In my `AppData\Roaming\geany\filedefs\filetypes.common`, I have set

```
caret=caret;;true
cursor_color=yellow
```

While the caret-setting (changing the default to a block cursor) works
(which obviously indicates that I configured the setting in the correct file),
the `cursor_color` setting does not seem to have any effect,
as the cursor is still a light grey.

What did I do wrong? 
How can I set the color of the cursor in Geany?

Answer (score 2):

0. Open Terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+T ).
1. Hit  " sudo gedit /usr/share/geany/filedefs/filetypes.common ".
2. Replace line "caret=caret" with "caret=0xffffff;0x0;false;false".
3. Hit ctrl+s (save changes) and exit; restart geany.

NOTE: Here I have used color WHITE (0xffffff), you can use any color, just put the hex color code of that color. For eg: 0xff0000 for RED, 0x00ff00 for GREEN etc.

Comment: Except that your solution is targeting towards the Unix/Linux version of Geany, I think it should work in Windows too. I'll give it a try and accept your answer, if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to have any effect. I set the line to `caret=0x3C3505;;true` and restarted Geany, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download new color schemes using GitHub.
2. In your home/hidden files, replace Geany color schemes with what you download.
3. Go into the color schemes folder and edit the `.conf` file using any text editor with

   ```
   caret=0xffffff;0x0;false;false
   ```

   NOTE: Here I have used color WHITE (`0xffffff`). 
   You can use any color; just enter the hex color code of that color. 
   For example: `0xff0000` for RED, `0x00ff00` for GREEN, etc.

Comment: Do you know by chance, which directory the Windows version of Geany consideres the home directory? I tried to apply this change by using the Geany menu "Werkzeuge/Konfigurationsdateien" (in the English version, this is likely "tools/config files", and selecting _filetypes.common_, which contains the setting for `caret`.

Comment: Just found out that most likely, the home location for Geany is `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\geany\filedefs`. However, a change to the caret definition does not take any effect.